# Advanced template matching

Tags: python, image, opencv, templates, matching

It's been weeks since I am looking for an “advanced” template matching. My goal is to find a template picture into a bigger one.

I am currently using Python for this purpose, especially OpenCV. **I am aware** that there is a lot of tutorials for this purpose on Google, however **I didn't find any method**s which perfectly fit my purpose. Indeed I am looking for a flexible template matching : differents resolution, differents space between shapes, even different scales, ...

**What I want to match :**

[image: Template image 1]

[image: Template image 2]

Both pictures should be found on this bigger screenshot :

[image: Bigger picture]

You can see that both templates aren't exactly the same. Indeed they come from two differents computers, with differents resolutions, Word version, ..

However a human could easily match thoses pictures.

*Some others example of template with differents resolutions :*

[image: Template 3]

[image: Template 4]

**What I tried, and why it isn't working:**

- Traditional [template matching](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) : not flexible enough , every pixel has to fit perfectly
- [Feature matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html) (SIFT, SURF, ORB, BRIEF, …) : not enough keypoints, not accurate enough on small pictures
- Shape detection : Found shapes aren't same on both picture, which makes it difficult to match
- Histogram comparison / Hu moments : not accurate enough, match some pictures which shouldn't
- [Tesseract OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) : May find differents text / Not all pictures got text

**What I may try to do:**

- Machine learning : to train an artifical intelligence to find similarities. However I not an expert in this field, and it may not be adapted, because I have never seen before a machine learning with 2 pictures as input.

As you probably understand, I am open to any suggestions which could make these pictures match !

Thank you

Comment: The flavor of deep learning you could use to solve this problem is object detection.

Comment: I am curious about your histogram matching, when you find a match are you finding where in the image it is? You might be able to eliminate false positives with another technique, such as ordinary template matching if you can now resize the candidate match to see if they match

Comment: Thank you for your answer @shortcipher3
Isn't object detection more oriented about classification issue ? I am trying to detect whether two pictures matches without know what is represented on.

For histogram matching : I crop different areas with different dimensions on the bigger picture, then I compare it with histogram comparison.
I already tried to resize a picture to fit the other, however sometimes space between shapes/words is not the same. Because of this, template matching doesn’t always work..

Answer (score 0):

Shape match algorithms,such as: linemod should work(or shapeMatching in halcon); however, if the model image will not change in angle, matchShape + normalized should also work(after contour/edge extracting)